# Python hash structure

Tags: python, hash

I get as an input N*M matrix (tuple of tuples), values from 1 to 9.

What is the best way to hash this structure, so I can get the place (x,y) of every 8 value? (8 for example, can be 5 or 7...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to find the location of 5s and 7s and 8s, it may be more efficient to store all the locations in a dict with one pass through the matrix, instead of one pass for the 5s, one pass for the 7s, etc...

```
loc = {}    
for x in range(N):
    for y in range(M):
        loc.setdefault(matrix[x][y], []).append((x,y))
```

Comment: but I would like to access with O(1), since my program searches all the time for values in changing matrix

Comment: Dict access is O(1). See the [TimeComplexity wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 1):

"Hash" is the wrong word for this. You just want to search a 2D array for a particular value. Maybe something like this...

```
height = len(data)
width = len(data[0])
eights = [(x, y) for y in range(height) for x in range(width) if data[x][y] == 8]
```

Comment: but I would like to access with O(1), since my program searches all the time for values in changing matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
[(x,y) for x in range(N) for y in range(M) if matrix[x][y] == 8]
```